# Ford Mondeo 2010 MK4 P2002 Error code

Tags: ford, mondeo, diesel-particulate-filter

I've had P2002 error code on my Ford Mondeo MK4 2010 2.0tdci for a couple of months now and I can't find the fault. It's been to the mechanics and had new dfp hoses, a manual regeneration, a good run down the motorway and finally a new DPF fitted but everytime I get the error code taken off, it comes back on within 20 miles of use. 
The car is running fine and just passed its MOT. Any suggestions as to what to try next? This is becoming expensive.

Comment: Well, knowing what engine you have may help... also, year, mileage etc etc

Comment: Hi Solar Mike. Sorry, it's 2.0tdci durotech 2010 mk4 with 85000 miles.

Comment: Have you checked the EGR operation and is it clean? just a thought...

Comment: Not yet. I'll get it checked. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you got the problem solved?
I also have the same DTC code P2002 on my Mondeo 2.0 tdci duratorq -07 but I get it together with P1335 wich is a fault in the EGR System. Did you check your EGR system?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be something with the DPF. Most common cause for this error are broken hoses going to the differential pressure sensor. Another thing might be broken sensor itself or the wiring going to it. But you are saying that whole DPF was changed, did it include the change of the sensor as well? Also double check the hoses, maybe they still leak somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I had the hoses changed first. I didn't get the sensor changed because the mechanics said it was ok but I've got one on order now. Hadn't thought about the wiring though.

Comment: Just had the sensor changed and the error removed them gave it a blast down the motorway. Engine warning light came back on still with the same code P2002. It's now had new hoses, new sensor, manual regeneration and new DPF and I still can't find what the issue is.